# Php mod_rewrite code not redirect to expected link structure

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a php page which show business page of user which is redirect from index.php page.

Some Index.php page code is bellow:

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$mid = (int) $res['mid'];
$uname_d = inputvalid($res['uname']);   
$profile_pic_d = inputvalid($res['profile_picture']);   
$mid = base64_encode($mid);
echo "<div class='members'>";
echo "<h4><a href='businesspage.php?profile=$uname_d'>$uname_d</a></h4>";    
?>
<img src="<?php echo "$upload_directory/$profile_pic_d"; ?>" width="99" 
height="100"/>
<?php
echo "</div>";
}
```

Now It's redirect to this link:

```
http://localhost/wisper/businesspage.php?profile=creativeartbd
```

So I'm trying to redirect this link to show look like this:

```
http://localhost/wisper/creativeartbd
```

**.htaccess code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond $1 !^businesspage.php
RewriteRule ^wisper/(.*?)$ wisper/businesspage.php?profile=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

But unfortunately It's not working. Is there any problem in the code ?

**Update:**

Now index.php page code is bellow:

```
echo "<h4><a href='$uname_d'>$uname_d</a></h4>";
```

But the link is redirect to this style which i don't want and it's show object not found:

```
http://localhost/businesspage.php?profile=creativeartbd
```

I want Link should be look like this:

```
http://localhost/wisper/creativeartbd
```

.htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond $1 !^businesspage.php
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ businesspage.php?profile=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Does `businesspage.php` live in the `wisper` folder or not? The last `RewriteCond` and the `RewriteRule` are inconsistent there.

Comment: @Boldewyn, Yes businesspage.php page is there in wisper folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<h4><a href='businesspage.php?profile=$uname_d'>$uname_d</a></h4>";
```

Your code tells the browser to go to `http://localhost/wisper/businesspage.php?profile=creativeartbd`, so of course the browser is going to go there when it clicks on the link. mod_rewrite is on the server's end, not the browser's. You need to make sure your links look the way you want them to look:

```
echo "<h4><a href='/wisper/$uname_d'>$uname_d</a></h4>";
```

Comment: After click this link it's show Object Not Found.

Comment: @Alex is the htaccess file in your document root (notin the `wisper` folder?

Comment: the .htaccess file in wisper folder.

Comment: @Alex then the rewrite base needs to be `/wisper/` and you need to remove all the `wisper/` from your `RewriteRule`. Or, just move it to your document root.

Comment: @Alex I said: **the rewrite base needs to be `/wisper/`**

Comment: Sorry, may be you don't understand my point that which link structure I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wisper/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ businesspage.php?profile=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

It will pass each url hit to the `businesspage.php?profile=?` you should customize your link to distinguish the user profile links and the other website links

For example

```
echo "<h4><a href='profile/$uname_d'>$uname_d</a></h4>";
```

And your rewrite rule would be

```
 RewriteRule ^profile/(.*?)$ businesspage.php?profile=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Check my Updated please.

Comment: do you understand which link structure I want ?

Comment: I want Link should be look like this: http://localhost/wisper/creativeartbd but now it's going to this link: http://localhost/businesspage.php?profile=creativeartbd and it's show object not found.